# Manipulate with multiple locators

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction

How can I work with tables/lists of `Locator`s under manipulate?

Note this is very similar to this question:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51956/2079

The closest I've come is this:

```
 n = 3
 Manipulate[
    Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], Line[{{0, 0}, a[1]}]}],
    Sequence @@ 
      Map[{{a[#], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]}, Locator} & ,
           Range[n]] // Evaluate]
```

[image]

However any attempt to referece `a` by a variable index fails:

```
 n = 3
 Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], Map[Line[{{0, 0}, a[#]}] &, Range[n]]}],
 Sequence @@ 
   Map[{{a[#], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]}, Locator} & ,
     Range[n]] // Evaluate]
```

> "coordinate a[1] should be a pair of numbers.. "

My best attempt at following the approach in the linked answer also fails:

```
 n = 3
 Manipulate[
    Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}]],
    {{data, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]}, ControlType -> None},
 Sequence @@ 
    Map[{{Dynamic[data[[#]]], RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2}]}, Locator} & , 
    Range[n]] // Evaluate]
```

> "Manipulate argument {{data[[1]],{-0.864708,0.897225}},Locator} does 
>   not have the correct form for a variable specification."

This came up working on this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80099/2079 by the way.

Comment: First you should read the section on locators in this Documentation Center [article](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html). It discusses using multiple locator in a `Manipulate` expression. Second, you should consider whether a simple [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) will be a better solution than `Manipulate` expression as solution to your problem.

Comment: ah! thanks @m_goldberg.  The answer lies in creating a single locator call of the form `{ pts , list_of_initial_points }, Locator}`, rather than a sequence of separate Locator calls `{ { point1 ,init1} , Locator } ,{ { point2 ,init2} , Locator } ..` ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 3;
Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}],Line[{{0, 0}, a[[#]]} & /@Range[Length@a]]}],
 {{a, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], Line[Tuples[{{{0, 0}}, a}]]}],
 {{a, RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}]}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> True}]
```

Answer (score 1):

for completeness here is the `LocatorPane` version suggested by @m_goldberg comment.

```
 DynamicModule[{pt = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 2}]},
   LocatorPane[Dynamic@pt,
     Graphics[{Circle[],
        Line[{{0, 0}, Dynamic@pt[[#]]}] & /@ Range@Length@pt}]]]
```